# Writing data of a dictionary containing enum values to a JSON file using Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, data-extraction

I have an enum as shown below:

```
class University(Enum):
    STUDENT = 1
    PROFESSOR = 2
```

I have a dictionary named 'university_info' containing data as shown below:

```
[{<University.PROFESSOR: 2>: {'iD': 1234,
 'Name': 'John Samuel'
 'Phone': 7531670961,
 'City': 'Rochester'}},

 {<University.PROFESSOR: 2>: {'iD': 5678,
 'Name': 'Alisa Potter',
 'Phone': 8904124567,
 'City': 'Manhattan'}}]
```

I want to write this data into a JSON file. I am using the below code:

```
import json
fileName='test.json'
def writeToJSONFile(data):
    with open(fileName, 'a+') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
```

then I am calling the function on the dictionary as:

```
writeToJSONFile(university_info)
```

it is giving me an error:

```
key <University.PROFESSOR: 2> is not a string
```

but when I am doing:

```
writeToJSONFile(str(university_info))
```

It is printing result correctly

May I know how can I print the result into JSON without converting it into str?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain JSON can only encode the following.

- object (Python dict)
- array  (Python list)
- string (Python str)
- number (Python float or int)
- "true" (Python True)
- "false" (Python False)
- "null" (Python None)

That's it.  You must define a custom encoder and decoder for other types, which will usually also involve encoding it as a plain JSON structure. For example, an Enum could be `[string, number]`. But the default implementation does not include that.

Comment: so Is there a way that I can only convert the enum into string but not the other values? Because the way I am doing: writeToJSONFile(str(university_info)), is converting the whole dictionary into string

Comment: Sure, just use a string as the key. Some other bit of code could replace it.